# How to use numba with readonly dict as input?

Tags: python, dictionary, numba

I tried `typed.Dict.empty(types.uint8[:], types.int32)`, but it is not working.

```
import struct
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

#@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def process_uids(uid, data, XYtoBCID ):
    indices = np.where(data == uid)
    uid_row = np.zeros(data.size, dtype=bool)
    hitCnt, misCnt = 0, 0
    for idx in nb.prange(indices[0].size):
        ptX, ptY = indices[0][idx], indices[1][idx]
        #ptStr = struct.pack("@HH", ptX, ptY)
        ptS = np.array([ptX, ptY], dtype=np.uint16)
        ptS.setflags(write=0, align=0)
        ptStr = ptS.tobytes()
        if ptStr in XYtoBCID:
            bcid = XYtoBCID[ptStr]
            uid_row[bcid-1] = True
            hitCnt += 1
        else:
            misCnt += 1
    return hitCnt, misCnt, uid_row

def main():
    np.random.seed(42)
    data = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3], size=(20, 20))
    print(data)
    random_values = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 301), size=(20, 20), replace=True)
    indices_to_replace = np.random.choice(range(20 * 20), size=100, replace=False)
    random_values_flat = random_values.flatten()
    random_values_flat[indices_to_replace] = 0
    random_values = random_values_flat.reshape((20, 20))
    XYtoBCID = {}
    #XYtoBCID = nb.typed.Dict.empty(nb.types.uint8[:], nb.types.int32)
    for idx, value in enumerate(random_values.flatten(), start=1):
        posX, posY = np.unravel_index(idx-1, random_values.shape)
        #posStr = struct.pack("@HH", posX, posY)
        posStr = np.array([posX, posY], dtype=np.uint16)
        if value > 0:
            XYtoBCID[posStr.tobytes()] = value
    #print(XYtoBCID)
    values, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
    mtxCellBarcode = sp.sparse.lil_matrix((values[-1], data.size), dtype=bool)
    hitCnt,misCnt = 0,0
    for uid in values[1:]:
        hit, miss, uid_row = process_uids(uid, data, XYtoBCID)
        hitCnt += hit
        misCnt += miss
        mtxCellBarcode[uid-1, :] = uid_row
    print(f'Hit:{hitCnt}, Miss:{misCnt}.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is modified version that compiles with [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) (it uses `nb.types.Tuple` and `nb.typed.Dict`):

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

dict_key_type = nb.types.Tuple((nb.types.uint16, nb.types.uint16))
dict_value_type = nb.types.int32


@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def process_uids(uid, data, XYtoBCID):
    indices = np.where(data == uid)
    uid_row = np.zeros(data.size, dtype=nb.types.uint8)
    hitCnt, misCnt = 0, 0
    for idx in nb.prange(indices[0].size):
        t = (np.uint16(indices[0][idx]), np.uint16(indices[1][idx]))
        if t in XYtoBCID:
            bcid = XYtoBCID[t]
            uid_row[bcid - 1] = True
            hitCnt += 1
        else:
            misCnt += 1
    return hitCnt, misCnt, uid_row



def work_numba(data, XYtoBCID):
    values, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
    mtxCellBarcode = sp.sparse.lil_matrix((values[-1], data.size), dtype=bool)
    hitCnt, misCnt = 0, 0
    for uid in values[1:]:
        hit, miss, uid_row = process_uids(uid, data, XYtoBCID)
        hitCnt += hit
        misCnt += miss
        mtxCellBarcode[uid - 1, :] = uid_row
    return hitCnt, misCnt


def main():
    np.random.seed(42)
    data = np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3], size=(20, 20))
    random_values = np.random.choice(
        np.arange(1, 301), size=(20, 20), replace=True
    ).astype(np.int32)
    indices_to_replace = np.random.choice(range(20 * 20), size=100, replace=False)
    random_values_flat = random_values.flatten()
    random_values_flat[indices_to_replace] = 0
    random_values = random_values_flat.reshape((20, 20))

    XYtoBCID = nb.typed.Dict.empty(dict_key_type, dict_value_type)

    for idx, value in enumerate(random_values.flatten(), start=1):
        posX, posY = np.unravel_index(idx - 1, random_values.shape)
        if value > 0:
            XYtoBCID[(np.uint16(posX), np.uint16(posY))] = value

    hitCnt, misCnt = work_numba(data, XYtoBCID)
    print(f"Hit:{hitCnt}, Miss:{misCnt}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running this code prints:

```
Hit:224, Miss:81
```

Comment: There is `nb.types.boolea` <https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html#numbers>